# string or binary data would be truncated. in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, insert, nvarchar

How to overcome this?

I have insert statements for large tables. there were lot of columns in those tables.

Is there any simple way to find the column which is causing above error?

Comment: vote to get this fixed https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/339410/please-fix-the-string-or-binary-data-would-be-truncated-message-to-give-the-column-name

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way is to increase the length of the column which is giving you the error "string or binary data would be truncated. in sql server".

Now to find which column is giving that error you can check [How to find what column caused the String or binary data would be truncated message](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/datamgmt/datadesign/how-to-find-what-column/)

First thing we need to know is what the columns are in the table that are (n)chars or (n)varchar

```
select column_name
from information_schema.columns
where table_name = 'temp'
and data_type in('varchar','char','nvarchar','nchar')
```

Output:

```
column_name
————–
Col1
Col2
Col3
Col4
Col5
```

That was easy, now we want to know the max length of the data in each column

```
declare @sql varchar(8000)
select @sql = 'select  0 as _col0 ,'
select @sql +=   'max(len( ' + column_name+ ')) AS ' + column_name + ',' 
from information_schema.columns
where table_name = 'temp'
and data_type in('varchar','char','nvarchar','nchar')

select @sql = left(@sql,len(@sql) -1)
select @sql +=' into MaxLengths from temp'

--select @sql -debugging so simple, a caveman can do it

exec (@sql)
```

That code basically creates and runs the following

```
select  0 as _col0 ,
    max(len( Col1)) AS Col1,
    max(len( Col2)) AS Col2,
    max(len( Col3)) AS Col3,
    max(len( Col4)) AS Col4,
    max(len( Col5)) AS Col5 
into MaxLengths 
from temp
```

If we now look in the MaxLengths table we will see the following

```
select * from MaxLengths

_col0   Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4    Col5
---------------------------------------------------
0   13  20  6   4   15
```

Next to figure out is what the max length of the column itself is in the table that we want to insert into
Run the following query

```
select character_maximum_length,column_name
from information_schema.columns
where table_name = 'TestTrunc'
and data_type in('varchar','char','nvarchar','nchar')
```

Result

```
character_maximum_length    column_name
--------------------------------------------
10              Col1
15              Col2
20              Col3
3               Col4
10              Col5
```

We will again do this dynamically and insert the values into another table

```
declare @sql varchar(8000)
select @sql = 'select 0 as _col0, '
select @sql +=   '' + convert(varchar(20),character_maximum_length)+ ' AS ' + column_name + ',' 
from information_schema.columns
where table_name = 'TestTrunc'
and data_type in('varchar','char','nvarchar','nchar')

select @sql = left(@sql,len(@sql) -1)
select @sql +=' into TempTrunc '

--select @sql -debugging so simple, a caveman can do it

exec (@sql)
```

Now we can see what we have in the two tables

```
select 'TempTrunc' as TableNAme,* from TempTrunc
union all
select 'MaxLengths' as TableNAme,* from MaxLengths

TableNAme   _col0   Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4    Col5
-------------------------------------------------------------
TempTrunc   0   10  15  20  3   10
MaxLengths  0   13  20  6   4   15
```

As you can see, all columns except for Col3 will cause the truncation problem
Of course we want to do something like this, it will tell us which columns have truncation problems

```
select  case when  t.col1 > tt.col1 then 'truncation' else 'no truncation' end as Col1,
 case when  t.col2 > tt.col2 then 'truncation' else 'no truncation' end as Col2,
 case when  t.col3 > tt.col3 then 'truncation' else 'no truncation'  end as Col3,
 case when  t.col4 > tt.col4 then 'truncation'  else 'no truncation' end as Col4,
 case when  t.col5 > tt.col5 then 'truncation' else 'no truncation'  end as Col5
   from MaxLengths t
join TempTrunc tt on t._col0 = tt._col0

Col1        Col2        Col3            Col4        Col5
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
truncation  truncation  no truncation        truncation      truncation
```

[Source](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/datamgmt/datadesign/how-to-find-what-column/)

Comment: I have seen this solution earlier. But its not suitable in the case of temp tables and also I have asked for a simple solution yaar

Comment: @GiriPrasad:- The problem is there is no simple solution for this. People have reported this issue to MS but as of now there is no simple approach. This is by far a better approach to proceed with!

Comment: Yeah. I have seen that. I thought any one will be having simple approach. Thats why I have posted it

Comment: @GiriPrasad:- I dont think there is any simple approach for that. However the query which is posted above doesnt sound that complicated, however I agree that there is a bunch of query to execute but those are not complicated! ;)

Answer (score 1):

I believe you already know that this is related with inserting a string value into a column with less size
You can query table columns from know table names and compare them.

```
select
    OBJECT_NAME(object_id),
    name,
    max_length,
    precision,
    scale
from sys.columns where object_id in (
    select object_id from sys.tables where name in ('tbl','Emp')
)
```